# Display a gtk.Spinner in a gtk.ToolButton

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Is there a way to display a `gtk.Spinner` on a `gtk.ToolButton` instead of a stock image ?

I have tried this :

```
toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
toolbar.set_style(gtk.TOOLBAR_BOTH)

toolbutton = gtk.ToolButton()
spinner = gtk.Spinner()
toolbutton.set_icon_widget(spinner)
toolbutton.set_label('Some text')
toolbar.insert(toolbutton, 0)
```

The label text is been displayed but not the spinner.
What is wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in fact the real code it's different of my original post :

I call `toolbutton.set_icon_widget(spinner)` after `window.show_all()`.

So, i have added `spinner.show()` after the `set_icon_widget()` method and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import gtk

toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
toolbar.set_style(gtk.TOOLBAR_BOTH)

toolbutton = gtk.ToolButton()
spinner = gtk.Spinner()
toolbutton.set_icon_widget(spinner)
toolbutton.set_label('Some text')
toolbar.insert(toolbutton, 0)

spinner.start ()
window = gtk.Window ()
window.add (toolbar)
window.set_size_request (300, 100)
window.show_all ()

window.connect ('destroy', lambda window: gtk.main_quit ())

gtk.main ()
```